# Visual Studioのソリューションに既存のプロジェクトを複数まとめて追加する方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studioのソリューションファイル(*.sln)に、既存のプロジェクトファイル(*.csproj)を複数まとめて追加する機能やソフトウェアは存在するのでしょうか。

C#で100以上の画面を持つシステムを複数のチームで開発していますが、他のチームの開発やテストを手伝うなどのタイミングでソリューションファイルに複数個のプロジェクトファイルをまとめて追加したい場合があります。
またVisual Studioの起動やリビルドを遅くしないよう、機能単位でソリューションに含むプロジェクトを切り替えて管理したい場合もあります。
上記のケースでソリューションへ1プロジェクトずつ追加する作業は時間がかかって生産性が低下します。

本来はチームや機能ごとにソリューションファイルを分割してバージョン管理システムできれいに管理することが正しい運用かと思いますが、現状ではそうも行かずに低機能な自作ツールでソリューションファイルを書き換えて運用しています。

自作ツール以外でソリューションファイルを効率的に書き換えるソリューションがあればご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017ではプロジェクト読み込みの大幅な高速化が行われています（[15.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/11/20/large-c-and-vb-solutions-load-significantly-faster-in-15-5-update/)と[15.6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/04/04/load-solutions-faster-with-visual-studio-2017-version-15-6/)）。一度、全てのプロジェクトを一つのソリューションに含めて実際の読み込み時間を測定されてみてはどうでしょうか？
またVisual Studioにはプロジェクトのアンロード機能があります。一旦アンロードを行うと、次回以降は読み込まなくなるため、各メンバーが影響しないプロジェクトをアンロードしておく手もあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。VS2012ではアンロードしてもビルドが遅くロード時間が大変なことになっていましたが、VS2015, VS2017で劇的に高速化が図られていますので業務で使えるように頑張ります。マシンと環境が良くなればソリューションフォルダを作成して一括ロード/アンロードで手軽に運用できることは承知しているのですが…。